# Improve time response of an RoR Project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, passenger

In production the response time is very huge due to javascript loading, so i'm looking for a way to improve it without changing any line of code
Please note that i'm using:

- Ruby on Rails 3.2
- Passenger (Apache2)

Please give advice

Comment: Yes i mean initialisation script and css time. it takes more than 30s to load the root page ! so i'm looking for a way to reduce this response time

Comment: Maybe do you load a lot of scripts that don't need to be there : is your root page needing the 28.000 lines of the JS file ? So maybe can you split your code in different files.

Comment: the js loaded is the application.js file, so it pulls all le js which means the 28000 lines

Comment: Yes, but what I mean is that you could split `application.js` in a few files instead. For example you can have on `.js` by controller. With that, you don't load unnecessary libs on all pages, but just on the pages that need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you say you can't change the application, but to have to load 100kb of CSS and 1Mb of JS for the first page seems rather excessive. I would seriously look at trying to cut up the resources so that they are loaded on demand.

There aren't all that many 'fixes' that leave the codebase alone, but some of those are:

- Compress the resources (e.g. Using "Content-encoding=gzip", http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/).
- Optimise the order of resources (may need minor code changes - http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rtt.html#PutStylesBeforeScripts).
- Parallelise downloads across hostnames (may need minor code changes - http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rtt.html#ParallelizeDownloads).
- Put the content closer to the user (Use a CDN).
- Improve the end-to-end network infrastructure.
- Use aync resources (This may only give you the illusion of a faster app. The page may start rendering sooner, but depending on the nature of your JS, the app still may only be useable after it has all been downloaded - http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rtt.html#PreferAsyncResources)
- Use far-future HTTP expiry headers to increase the chances that a user who has already visited the site does not need to download the content again.

Answer (score 0):

Load you JS from a Content Delivery Network.

If you show some profiling information for the loading times (The Chrome developer tools profiler is enough), we will be able to give better advice.

Comment: Chrome Developer tools shows that: content of css file (97,7KB) takes 14,53 s, and that a js file (998KB) takes 9,93 s

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the delivery of the CSS. You should optimize that. Also, it seems your internet may be slow or you server may be overburdened.

Comment: there are about 2 800 lines in the css file and 28 000 lines in the js file. I have an other app on the server written in php wich response quickly, so i'm sure that the server is not overburdened and that my internet is fast enough

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the defer attribute:
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/placejs.html

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, it's just passenger spinning up but should only happen on the first page load after a deployment.

If it's happening often, that means passenger is shutting your app down, so you should look at configuring passenger a little more.

One option is to ensure you always have at least one instance running using this option:

```
PassengerMinInstances 1
```